# [University : Functions and Set Theory]

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

First things first, This question was translated from another language, Please forgive me for any mistakes.

Let $f$ be a function from A to B ($f:A\to B$) and there is $C \subseteq A$.
A. Prove that $C \subseteq f^{-1} (f(C))$

B. Prove that if $f$ is injective then $C=f^{-1} (f(C))$.

C. Give an example for sets A,B,C and function $f:A\to B$  in such way that $C \subseteq f^{-1} (f(C))$

My way of answering:

A. If $C$ is a subset of $A$, then the origin of $C$ is used by the function $f$ is a subset group of $A$ that is defined like this: $f^{-1} (C) = \{x\in A | f(x) \in C\}$. And from there I am stuck.

**EDIT:** Question was solved by myself, without any help, but I'll still tick the answer so other people can see the answer as well. Thanks for everyone.

Comment: If you want to prove that $X\subseteq Y$ for sets X and Y, you want to show that for every $x\in X$, we have $x\in Y$. With that in mind, start your proof with “Let $x\in C$” and then try proving $x\in f^{-1}(f(C))$ using the definitions.

Comment: Maybe start with part C. Use small sets for $A$ and $B$. Then you'll see what happens, and likely be able to figure out parts A and B. In particular, depicting the function with arrows from elements of $A$ to elements of $B$ should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x in C, then f(x) in f(C) and
x in { x : f(x) in f(C) } = $f^{-1}$(f(C)).